# hide button after saving data to database

Tags: php, mysql

i created a group and what i wanted to do is when i join the group the join button should hide. but i dont know how to do it.. tbl_group is the list of created group and when you join the group the id will be saved on a diff table.. this code is for showing all list of groups.

**group.php**

```
<?php 
  $db = new Group($conn);
  $res = $db->g_viewlist();
  foreach ($res as $key => $value){
?>      
  <div class="col-lg-12" align="center" style="border:1.5px solid #59960b;padding-bottom:10px;padding-top:10px;">
  <button class="btn2 btn-2 join" data-id="<?php echo $value['g_id']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#joinModal" style="padding: 2px 2px;margin-left:50%"><strong> Join</strong></button>
                                  
  <img src="./<?php echo $value['g_image']; ?>"class="pull-left" class="img-square" height="70" width="70" alt="Avatar">
  <p align="left">
  <strong class="font-1" style="color:#59960b;"><?php echo $value['g_name'];?>          </strong><br>
  <small style="font-family:courier,'new courier';" class="text">Member Since  2008<br></small>
  <small style="font-family:courier,'new courier';" class="text-muted">Description:<?php echo $value['g_desc']; ?></small><br>
  </p>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

**SQL Query** for showing all list of groups.

```
public function g_viewlist(){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_group ";
    $result = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
    $result->execute();
    $data = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

[image]
this table is where i store the user id and the group id this is a diff table..assuming the g_id = 25 from tbl_group and group_id =25 from tbljoingroup [image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve the array of groups user is a member of and inside your foreach loop just search through this list. If user is a member of `$value['g_id']` just skip loop iteration with `continue`.

If you want to hide only the button and still display the rest of the code then do something like this:

```
<?php 
  $db = new Group($conn);
  $res = $db->g_viewlist();
  foreach ($res as $key => $value) {
?>      
    <div class="col-lg-12" align="center" style="border:1.5px solid #59960b;padding-bottom:10px;padding-top:10px;">
    <?php if (!$user.memberOf($value['g_id'])) { ?>
      <button class="btn2 btn-2 join" data-id="<?php echo $value['g_id']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#joinModal" style="padding: 2px 2px;margin-left:50%"><strong> Join</strong></button>
    <?php } ?>

    <img src="./<?php echo $value['g_image']; ?>"class="pull-left" class="img-square" height="70" width="70" alt="Avatar">
    <p align="left">
    <strong class="font-1" style="color:#59960b;"><?php echo $value['g_name'];?>          </strong><br>
    <small style="font-family:courier,'new courier';" class="text">Member Since  2008<br></small>
    <small style="font-family:courier,'new courier';" class="text-muted">Description:<?php echo $value['g_desc']; ?></small><br>
    </p>
  </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

If you have user object saved in `$user` then create `memberOf()` method which will return `true` if user is a member of the group or `false` otherwise.

**Note: Do not search database on each `memberOf()` execution. Do it once and save results in object's property for reuse.**

Comment: @AlfieGaring My answer still stands. Retrieve list of user's groups by querying `tbljoingroup` same way you are querying `tbl_group` just make sure you get the data for logged in user and use `foreach` inside your `foreach` to test if user is a member of the group.

Comment: so you mean i need to make another `foreach` for checking if the users are member of the group. cause `<?php if (!$user.memberOf($value['g_id'])) { ?>
      <button class="btn2 btn-2 join" data-id="<?php echo $value['g_id']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#joinModal" style="padding: 2px 2px;margin-left:50%"><strong> Join</strong></button>
    <?php } ?>` inside the if statement your referring to the id of the group not the id of the users... can you edit your answer??

Comment: @AlfieGaring You have one user logged in, his/her data in session, right? I referred to this user with `$user` variable which is an object in my example. You want this object to store currently logged user's data like it's id. Then you want to create a method in this class `memberOf($groupId)` which will retrieve groups (from database) user is a member of and check if `$groupId` is there using `foreach` loop.

Comment: i got an error 'Call to undefined function memberOf()'

Comment: @AlfieGaring Because it's just an example of a class I want you to create which will store user's data and then add `memberOf($groupId)` method to id for easy checking if current user is a member of a group.